# Rails find начиная с определенного id до первого. Как реализовать?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Случай такой: Есть две секции. В первой указываются последние 5 записей из БД. Это я делаю так:

```
 Model.limit(5).order('id desc')
```

Но как сделать, чтобы во второй секции показывало все остальные записи с первого по (COUNT - 5) by DESC?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: предположу, что так

    Model.limit(200000).offset(5).order('id desc')

но, скорее всего, самым оптимальным решением будет получить все одним массивом, вывести пять первых в одном месте, а остальное - в другом.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Model.offset(5).order('id desc')
```